# DisconnectionError after upgrade to appengine 1.7.6

Tags: google-app-engine

I use gae with Python 2.7, after I upgraded to gae 1.7.6, my unit tests are broken. I'm using nose and nosegae for the unit testing. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Any idea would be really appreciated. I've feeling that this is related to webob 1.2.3 being promoted to GA.

```
    self.app.post(task['url'], params, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 835, in post
    content_type=content_type)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 807, in _gen_request
    expect_errors=expect_errors)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 1118, in do_request
    self._check_status(status, res)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 1154, in _check_status
    res)
AppError: Bad response: 500 Internal Server Error (not 200 OK or 3xx redirect for http://localhost/task/request_log)
<pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1089, in __call__
    method(*args, **kwargs)
  File &quot;/Users/***/projects/game_server/game_service/events.py&quot;, line 184, in post
    inputs = pickle.loads(self.request.body)
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 677, in _body__get
    self.make_body_seekable() # we need this to have content_length
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 922, in make_body_seekable
    self.copy_body()
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 945, in copy_body
    self.body = self.body_file.read(self.content_length)
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 1528, in readinto
    + &quot;(%d more bytes were expected)&quot; % self.remaining
DisconnectionError: The client disconnected while sending the POST/PUT body (151 more bytes were expected)
</pre>
    self.app.post(task['url'], params, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 835, in post
    content_type=content_type)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 807, in _gen_request
    expect_errors=expect_errors)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 1118, in do_request
    self._check_status(status, res)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/WebTest-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/webtest/app.py", line 1154, in _check_status
    res)
AppError: Bad response: 500 Internal Server Error (not 200 OK or 3xx redirect for http://localhost/task/request_log)
<pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1089, in __call__
    method(*args, **kwargs)
  File &quot;/Users/***/projects/game_server/game_service/events.py&quot;, line 184, in post
    inputs = pickle.loads(self.request.body)
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 677, in _body__get
    self.make_body_seekable() # we need this to have content_length
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 922, in make_body_seekable
    self.copy_body()
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 945, in copy_body
    self.body = self.body_file.read(self.content_length)
  File &quot;/Users/***/Downloads/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py&quot;, line 1528, in readinto
    + &quot;(%d more bytes were expected)&quot; % self.remaining
DisconnectionError: The client disconnected while sending the POST/PUT body (151 more bytes were expected)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:** `headers` likely includes an incorrect Content-Length; fix it like so (assuming `params` is a `str`):

```
fixed_header = ('Content-Length', str(len(params)))
for i, header in enumerate(headers):
    if header[0] == 'Content-Length':
        headers[i] = fixed_header
        fixed_header = None
        break
if fixed_header:  # in case you're completely missing a Content-Length header
    headers.append(fixed_header)
```

---

[GAE 1.7.6](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/03/app-engine-176-released.html) changed the default webob from v0.9 to v1.2.3.  The code for retrieving request parameters (e.g., via `webob.Request.get()`) changed between these versions.

In 1.2.3, if you look at `BaseRequest.params` it creates a `NestedMultiDict` using `BaseRequest.POST` which in turn tries to read the body of the request using `cgi.FieldStorage()` which checks the Content-Length header.  If the Content-Length is incorrect, you'll get the `DisconnectionError` you experienced.

In 0.9, `Request.params` is built using `Request.str_params` which builds its `NestedMultiDict` using `Request.str_POST` (different than 1.2.3).  This in turn uses the pre-existing `Request.body_ file` which was read in using with `StringIO()` *without checking the Content-Length header*.

Thus you could get away with an incorrect Content-Length header in 1.7.5, but not in 1.7.6.

Task queue data is Base64 encoded.  I suspect that the `params` you're passing in on the first line of your traceback has been decoded from its Base64 format, but that you did not update the Content-Length header in `headers` to reflect this.  I suspect you got the headers from the task which you got from `GetTasks()` on the taskqueue stub whose Content-Length is set to the length of the original Base64 encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

The requests you're sending are probably lacking a proper Content-Length header.

Without it, the server can't determine exactly whether the client has uploaded all the data or if he got disconnected in the middle of the transfer.

Comment: Interesting, not sure why this happened since the request is prepared by WebTest, and it's broken only if I upgraded to appengine 1.7.6. I've skimmed through the webtest code, and the code set the content length

Comment: I have dozens of problems with 1.7.6. I got back to old_dev_appserver.

Comment: yeah I also revert back to 1.7.5 for now